# Mongodb sort by date

Tags: mongodb

I have a document with a field `_id` has type `ObjectId`, and a field `created_at` has type `Date`.

`_id` is of course increasing, and the value of `created_at` is current_date should be increasing.

So my question is :

1. Is there any chance that 2 documents, A and B, `A._id > B._id`, but `A.created_at < B.created_at`.
2. How to keep `created_at` as precise as possible, so the order of `created_at` corresponds to `_id`.

Comment: The only "real" chance would be where either the `_id` was generated at a source where the current "time" was behind the server instance and the `"created_at`" property was sourced from [`$currentDate`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/) on the server itself, rather than remotely. Also despite "best efforts" the `"created_at"` could in fact be "changed", whereas the `_id` field is "immutable" and **cannot** be changed. So an `ObjectId` in `_id` can never change from it's initial value, but any other property has no such distinction.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

In the above link you can see that mongodb uses timestamp to create its Id..So I think there can't be a scenario when this could occur, unless you change the system time where your server is running..

Comment: @AnirudhModi Well "technically" there can be cases just as mentioned. The other thing to consider is that the "time" in an `ObjectId` is **not** accurate to the millisecond, where as any BSON `Date` will be. So multiple `ObjectId` values can in fact represent the "same time" ( though still be independently monotonic ), where this is "less likely" in a field containing a full `Date` object, or a numeric version of a "more precise" time measurement. Depends on usage, and generally a reasonably broad topic.

Comment: @NeilLunn So you mean if I do `db.test.update({"_id": ObjectId()}, {"$currentDate": { "created_at": { "$type": 'date' }}}, {upsert: true})` then sort by `created_at` and sort by `_id` will have the same result?

Comment: Mostly. As long as your clocks on the "client" and "server" are in sync. I was generally covering cases where there "could" be a difference.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks, I'm using mongodb to store chat messages which require strict order both in server side and client side(android/ios), i use _id to sort those messages, but client side have to use created_at to sort their local messages, if this worked then you solved my problem.

Answer (score 38):

you can use order_by on documents collection like

**in Rails**

```
Product.order_by("created_at desc")
```

**in Mongodb**
for example

```
db.products.find().sort({"created_at": 1}) --- 1 for asc and -1 for desc
```

Comment: I use `_id` to sort documents, it's primary key and will be very fast.

Comment: @xcaptain you are aware that you can index any field or even multiple fields and they, too, will be very fast.

Comment: @xcaptain you can do by _id by 'created_at' with '_id' and _id by default indexed

Comment: @Sukanta Nope, the service side sorting is easy, sort by `_id` is enough for my situation. The hard part is that the client side use sqlite to store those documents server returns, sqlite doesn't recognize MongoId so my document must contain a time field and have the same order with `_id`

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose creates timestamps with field name "createdAt" and "updatedAt"

```
db.products.find().sort({"createdAt": 1})
```

Comment: This might create a very high latency with large amount of data, specially if this field is not indexed.

Comment: Good catch. We should index this if necessary.  Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963470/is-the-mongoose-timestamps-schema-option-indexed