# Is the Mongoose timestamps schema option indexed?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

Mongoose version >= 4.0 has a timestamps option which creates an `updatedAt` and `createdAt` field for schemas when `timestamps` is set to `true`.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps

Are the `updatedAt` and `createdAt` fields indexed?

Answer (score 33):

No they are not indexed, You have to do indexing by yourself, like any other field.

```
animalSchema.index({"createdAt": 1});
animalSchema.index({"updatedAt": 1});
```

Comment: Note to readers: the `1` means ascending order, not `true`.  And `-1` means descending, for those who don't often make site-level mondodb indexes ([not clearly documented](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) as of today).

Comment: @steampowered and it shouldn't matter what sort order index has if it's not compound.

Comment: @Andy good point.  I think I was also searching for documentation on simple sorting though, which obviously does matter.

Comment: For a [single-field](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#single-field) index and sort operations, the sort order (i.e. ascending or descending) of the index key does not matter because MongoDB can traverse the index in either direction.

Comment: Do you need separate lines for that? Doesn't `animalSchema.index({"createdAt": 1, "updatedAt": 1 })` work?

Comment: @true_north_404 That creates a Compound Index, whereas single lines create Single Field Indexes.